# Invalid hook call, next.js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have followed this tutorial to make a hamburger menu in react/next.js: https://youtu.be/prbOI7G0RvY

```
import { useState } from "react";
import user from '../styles/userview.module.css'

export function PageHeader() {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const openMenu= ()=> setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <header className={user.header}>
    <nav className={user.navbar}>
        <a className={user.navlogo}>[BrandLogo]</a>
      <ul className={isOpen === false ?
          user.navmenu : user.navmenu + ' ' + user.active}>
        <li className={user.navitem}>
            <a className={user.navlink}>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li className={user.navitem}>
          
            <a className={user.navlink}>About</a>
   
        </li>
        <li className={user.navitem}>
       
            <a className={user.navlink}>Contact</a>
  
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button className={isOpen === false ? user.hamburger : user.hamburger + ' ' + user.active}
                          onClick= {openMenu}
                          >
        <span className={user.bar}></span>
        <span className={user.bar}></span>
        <span className={user.bar}></span>
      </button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  )
}
```

But I keep getting this error message:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

It also indicates the problem is at this row:   `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);`

Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong?

EDIT:
Here is a picture of the exact error message: https://pasteboard.co/3xyAu6m8IeAW.png

EDIT 2:
I opened up my repo so you can see/test it on your own. Maybe the fault is in another file? The burgermenu is in the main-branch and ..components/userview and the page that imports and show the burgermenu is ../pages/hamburgertestfile.

Comment: Before watching tutorials please read the documentation carefully. You'll find all the questions here. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by a user of the Next.js-github-forum:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34858

Answer (score 0):

You cant call hooks from a regular javascript function as specified in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), therefore try importing React in your first line to convert the javascript function into a React function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

Comment: Oh, wow! And how do I do that (converting javascript function to React function)?

Comment: Was that sarcastic? assuming it's not, just add React in your import statement as I've indicated in my answer

Comment: Haha! No, I did not intend to be sarcastic, its just that I did, and it do not work. :( I am very new to this, thats why I was not sure if I understood what u meant exactly.

Comment: Please Teddy don’t give up on me. :(

Comment: @NonameAgent I cant see something else wrong in your code causing the error, but something else that I can see is that you need to make a default export of the component though the error message that you should be getting from this is not aligning with what you have. Just share the error message

Comment: Here is a picture of the exact error message: https://pasteboard.co/3xyAu6m8IeAW.png

Comment: hi @NonameAgent I think error ocuurs because you are returning a hook setIsOpen(!isOpen); in open menu.  it should be openMneu { setIsOpen(prevState=>!prevState)}? Let me know if it fixes the problem

Comment: I am so sorry @WasifAli but that just dont make any sense to me. I am very new to this, and even whithout your spelling errors, my editor dont accept that line, but makes it flame like a red torch. :( Could u perhaps be a little more specific what that should be replaced ans what to write?

Comment: @NonameAgent I tried to give you a solution not a grammer.  No doubt my spelling sucks just like your code indent. 
Anyway best of luck with your hamBurgur.

Comment: @WasifAli I did not intend to fault u in any way, I am happy for your help and concern. I just tried to express that Im so new to this that when my editor wont accept that line, I just don't know what to do with it. I really would (for real) appriciate a more clear/easy applicable comment on how to solve this. And yeah. I have read about hooks rules but I cant see where I am making a fault. :(